# Where is the syntax error in this XPath expression?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a XPath selector in my tests like this, which I copied directly from the dev tools in Chrome:

```
//*[@data-testid='menu-item']//strong[text()='Link for Image']
```

It works in the browser, but when I try to use this in my tests, I get this error message:

```
SyntaxError: Document.evaluate: The expression is not a legal expression
```

I think it's the last half of the selector that's having issues, but I'm not sure what is syntactically wrong...

Comment: I ran in an xpath tester online and no error.  How are you executing this?

Comment: The XPath expression looks to be valid

Comment: Hmm...I'm using a selenium based framework (wdio-utils) that uses webdriverio and cucumber libraries to run the tests

Comment: Can you share the entire code line?

Comment: Oh! My mistake, it's not a string in the xpath, it's a string interpolation! That seems to be why...`//*[@data-testid='menu-item']//strong[text()=${USER_STRING}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//*[@data-testid='menu-item']//strong[text()='Link for Image']` is a syntactically correct XPath expression.

Be sure to use double quotes as delimiters given that you're using single quotes within the XPath:

```
"//*[@data-testid='menu-item']//strong[text()='Link for Image']"
```

So, for example, if you're calling `document.evaluate()` in JavaScript, it would be

```
document.evaluate("//*[@data-testid='menu-item']//strong[text()='Link for Image']",
                  document)
```

---

**Update after OP's comment:**

> Oh! My mistake, it's not a string in the xpath, it's a string interpolation! That seems to be why...`//*[@data-testid='menu-item']//strong[text()=${USER_STRING}]`

So, in addition to the previously mentioned single/double quote concern for the entire XPath, you'll want to pay attention to whether `${USER_STRING}` itself has quotes, and what type they are.  If it has no quotes, then be sure to delimit the variable with them:

```
//*[@data-testid='menu-item']//strong[text()='${USER_STRING}']
```

And of course, you'll need to make sure that `${USER_STRING}` is actually being evaluated/substituted ahead of the function call expecting a well-formed XPath expression.

Finally, if `${USER_STRING}` comes from an unsecured source, be sure to sanitize before evaluating.